# Changing keyboard layout when keyboard is plugged with udev

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout, udev, setxkbmap

I want the activate a keyboard layout and to enable "sticky" modifier keys when my external keyboard is plugged in.

I've made this udev rule:

**/etc/udev/rules.d/keyboard.rules**

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{IdVendor}=="0853", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0100", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/maca/.Xauthority", RUN+="/home/maca/bin/sticky_keys", OWNER="maca"
```

That should run this script:

**/home/maca/bin/sticky_keys**

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/xkbset accessx sticky -twokey -latchlock
/usr/bin/xkbset exp 1 '=accessx' '=sticky' '=twokey' '=latchlock'
/usr/bin/setxkbmap us altgr-intl -option ctrl:nocaps -option lv3:ralt_switch
/usr/bin/touch /tmp/test
```

When I run the script the desired keyboard layout is activated and the modifier keys become sticky, however the script doesn't seem to work when the keyboard is plugged in. I know the script has successfully executed as there is a **/tmp/test** file that is generated.

I've tried with a `sleep 3` at the beginning of the script and also setting and exporting DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY from the script, but this does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I could get what I wanted by using udev to alias the device and to have a user systemd unit triggered when the device became available:

**/etc/udev/rules.d/keyboard.rules**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input" \
  , ATTRS{idVendor}=="0853" \
  , ATTRS{idProduct}=="0100" \
  , SYMLINK+="keyboard" \
  , TAG+="systemd"
```

**/home/maca/.config/systemd/user/sticky_keys.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Sticky keys and keyboard layout
After=dev-keyboard.device
BindsTo=dev-keyboard.device
Requisite=dev-keyboard.device

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/maca/bin/sticky_keys
StandardOutput=journal
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-keyboard.device
```

And then:

```
$ systemctl --user enable sticky_keys.service
```